# node.js: limit number of object Ids that an array contain in mongodb using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

May be my question is so simple but I'm not finding a solution for it.
I want to limit the size of **array of object Ids** in mongodb. I'm using mongoose.

how to do this using mongoose schema?

or The solution I'm thinking is first retrieve the document then calculate the size of array and after that return the validation failure error to the end user if it occurs.

Please help me find the better solution.

Answer (score 3):

There's no such thing in Mongoose, but you can define your own validation. According to [Mongoose documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-validate), you can do that:

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
  phone: [{
    type: ObjectId,
    validate: {
      validator: function() {
        return this.phone.length <= 100;
      },
      message: 'Array exceeds max size.'
    }
  }]
});
```

For an array the validator function is called for each element with the element as parameter. But you can check the property's length instead of validating an element.

That will work when you update your model instance with the `save` method. Validators are not run when using `User.update`.

Comment: As I said that I have a array of object ids. User can store at most say 3 ids into it. He can sent 0,1,more ids at once. Adding ids to the array is another api call so I want to assert that he is not able to store more than 3 ids into the array. What is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: See my edits to check the property's length. I don't know if it's the most efficient way, but it seems pretty simple though.

Comment: But there is a twist I forgot to mention in my question and comment that if user is added  one id , he can again use the same api to add more ids . That's the real problem I'm facing .

Comment: If you keep using the `save` method for for updates, the validator is called and it will work for you. The only problem is if you use `update`, and in that case there's nothing I can do for you.